# Standard Windows menu bars in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, user-interface, menubar

I noticed that adding a `MenuStrip` (from the Toolbox) to my form design doesn't yield a menu bar like the one seen in many native Windows applications. Instead I get a menu bar like Visual Studio's own. None of the style settings for `MenuStrip` appear to mimic the much more common native menu bar.

Is there a way to add a menu bar to my Windows Forms application that looks the same as the one you see in Notepad, Task Manager and others? (Preferably with the designer, but I wouldn't mind adding it programmatically either.)

Screenshot for illustration:

[image]

Comment: What about it is that different than the menu found in notepad or windows explorer? It is very similar to that found in office 2003, so it isn't unusual.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Go to your *Toolbox*, right click anywhere inside and select "Choose Items".

When the dialog loads and appears, scroll down til you see MainMenu. Add that to the toolbox, and you've got yourself a native menu bar!

Comment: Wow, I had no idea I could add stuff to my Toolbox like that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was not aware of this component. I gave it a go and it has *very* limited: I was not able to change the colour in the designer, no support for localisation, no images, etc.  If this is what you want, go for it.  There *are* reasons why this has been superseded by the MenuStrip.

Comment: Yep, it is. I don't need the versatility of the newer MenuStrip so I'm open to options like this. I also just found that it's a .NET Framework 2.0 class.

Comment: Yeh. If there's one thing I would love in the MainMenu, is the option to add images next to menu items...

Comment: Some of the constructors for `MenuItem` take an `Image` as a parameter, so I think images can be added but not from the designer.

Comment: @BoltClock: dear god, are you using pre-2.0 .NET?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: No, .NET 3.5 actually. I'm new :P

Comment: Please see my new answer below for a better alternative

Comment: Is it possible to add icons in MainMenu without altering the appearance?, OwnerDraw alters the Windows 7 style.

Comment: Oh my god, I have never know anything about the toolbox like that!

Comment: My Visual Studio 2022 preview crashes when i try to rename a menu item.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, that the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu?view=netframework-4.8.1) at  say: `This class is not available in .NET Core 3.1 and later versions.`

Answer (score 23):

You can do this by setting your form's `Menu` property, like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Menu = new MainMenu();
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("File");
        this.Menu.MenuItems.Add(item);
            item.MenuItems.Add("Save", new EventHandler(Save_Click));
            item.MenuItems.Add("Open", new EventHandler(Open_Click)); 
        item = new MenuItem("Edit");
        this.Menu.MenuItems.Add(item);
            item.MenuItems.Add("Copy", new EventHandler(Copy_Click));
            item.MenuItems.Add("Paste", new EventHandler(Paste_Click)); 
        // etc ...
}

private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // save
}
```

These menus will look like "normal" system menus.

I couldn't find any designer support for this, though.  In my defense, I didn't try real hard.

Comment: There is an easier solution to this. It can be found in the "Choose Items" dialog. The component's called "MainMenu", and has Form Designer support, too.

Comment: This is a great answer. It may not be as simple or friendly as using the designer, but it isn't worth a downvote.

Comment: I agree. This is a great answer, and will come in handy when I'm working on projects on computers that don't have an IDE installed! I just tried to upvote, but it says the question is too old, and I can't vote until the question is edited, huh?

Comment: @jts: it's edited (so you can undo your downvote), and I accept your apology. :) I am a dumbass, though - I did look through the Choose Items dialog and found 3 MainMenu controls in there, 2 of which were already checked although none was in my toolbox, so I gave up early. I try never to wrestle with Visual Studio after midnight.

Comment: I'm sorry. Don't be so hard on yourself, can happen to all of us :-)

Comment: I was looking for exactly this kind of code for writing winforms in F#. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using a the `MainMenu` component you can create your own renderer for the `MenuStrip` component.  The advantage here is being able to add images to `MenuStripItem` objects.  Here is the pastebin for the custom renderer:

[NativeRenderer](http://pastebin.com/Dgd1WYPL)

There are different themes that can be applied in the constructor of the renderer. Try them all to see the native themes.  To use this renderer simply set the instance to the `MenuStrip` Renderer property:

```
menuStrip.Renderer = new NativeRenderer([theme]);
```

Comment: Ooh, this looks useful! If I do end up using it (I've kinda moved on to [greener pastures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)), I'd much like to credit the source. Or is it in the public domain? :)

Comment: Sorry BoltClock, I haven't lurked here in quite some time.  I have been trying to find the original author (it was posted on code.google.com somewhere).  I will post the original link when I find it.

Comment: @BoltClock I found it! Please give all the credit to this genius: http://code.google.com/p/szotar/source/browse/trunk/Client/Szotar.WindowsForms/Base/NativeToolStripRenderer.cs

Comment: seems like it can't find the ToolbarTheme type

Answer (score 4):

I normally set the MenuStrip's `RenderMode` to `System` which gives a minimalist, single colour menu (no gradients or anything decadent like that).

If that does not go far enough, then you'll likely have to jump through some low-level hoops to get what you want.