# Using a Windows 7 style menustrip in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard Windows menu bars in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778109/standard-windows-menu-bars-in-windows-forms)

I am using windows forms and when I use a MenuStrip item, I get something that looks like this:

http://imgkk.com/i/ggn1.png

Is it possible to use menu strips like the ones the system uses, like in Windows Explorer, or Firefox, for example:

http://imgkk.com/i/cxyg.png

with Windows Forms, or C# in general?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using a [`MainMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mainmenu.aspx) instead of a `MenuStrip`. The `MainMenu` will pick up the underlying operating system's current style, whereas the `MenuStrip` does not. Even though `MainMenu` was replaced with `MenuStrip`, it is still supported going forwards (according to the MSDN docs).

`MenuStrip` is rendered entirely in C# and does not use the current operating system's styles, whereas the `MainMenu` control renders using the underlying OS API and does.

`MainMenu` might not be in your toolbox. To add it, right click in the toolbox, select "Choose Items..." and then make sure the MainMenu item is checked.

[This article](http://wyday.com/blog/2009/making-the-menus-in-your-net-app-look-professional/) explains the differences between `MainMenu` and `MenuStrip` in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a custom tool strip renderer,

http://code.google.com/p/szotar/source/browse/trunk/Client/Szotar.WindowsForms/Base/NativeToolStripRenderer.cs