# Making WinForm ContextMenu Background Gray?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

Context menus seem to have a default white background.
This looks pretty nice, but for consistency's sake, I'd like the context menu to be gray like with any other application.  How can I get this style for my context menu?

Comment: Are you using ContextMenu or ContextMenuStrip?  Don't mix them.

Comment: I'm using ContextMenuStrip,
ContextMenu doesn't appear to be available
Visual C# 2008 is what I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946241/using-a-windows-7-style-menustrip-in-windows-forms/2946298#2946298) for another similar question about menu items.

What you need to do is to use a [`ContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx) instead of a `ContextMenuStrip`. This will pick up the default colours (ie. gray) and styles set in the underlying operating system instead of its own defined colours and styles.

Comment: I'm using Visual C# 2008, and ContextMenuStrip is the only option in the toolbox (ContextMenu doesn't seem to be there)

Comment: @Soo: If you read my answer linked above, it tells you how to add `ContextMenu` into the toolbox.

Comment: While automatically getting the default OS colors and appearance for menus is why I always opt for the (technically) older ContextMenu, it doesn't easily support image icons out of the box.  I've used [this](http://wyday.com/blog/2008/vista-menu-with-icons-in-c-sharp/) quite successfully in the past to do just that, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
contextMenuStrip1.BackColor = Color.Pink;
```

Put that in the onLoad handler, or go to the properties and change the BackColor there :o)

Comment: Ok, cool! but... the context menu is flat, and the other ones appear to have depth.  I just want my context menu to look the same as all the others.

Comment: By explicitly setting a background colour, you are forcing a user to have this colour, even if they change their Windows styles to something different.