# Change winforms ugly MenuStrip design to Windows' default

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

[image: form test]

Is there any way I can change the MenuStrip design back to Windows' default? I've tried changing the "renderMode" property, without success. Is it even possible to accomplish this in C#?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2778254/976080) will do what you need since the question is the same as yours, as a simple search would have yielded.

Comment: @Grant Winney: Looks like the images in that question are long gone. Good thing that question is marked as a duplicate of another (one of my own, I realize).

Comment: @Grant Winney: I could get them merged, actually. They're excellent merge candidates.